# Typhoeus not working on ubuntu with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, typhoeus

I am trying to do `GET` request via SSL, and getting the response code as `0` and response body as blank.

REQUEST

`Typhoeus::Request.get("https://www.example.com", headers: { 'Accept' => "application/json"}, ssl_verifypeer: false, userpwd: 'username' + ":" + 'pwd', sslversion: :sslv3))`

RESPONSE:

`"ETHON: performed EASY url= response_code=0 return_code=peer_failed_verification total_time=0.22201"`

The same URL is working on terminal via CURL also it is working on mac machine too.

Comment: did u solve this issue?

Comment: @poojaagarwal
 Yes you need to add "ssl_verifyhost: 0" to headers, refer here for more info https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/355